# window.open works in Firefox but not IE or Chrome

Tags: javascript, html

I have looked at the other similar answers but can't seem to see what I'm looking for. I'm trying to open a window containing a basic html page as a help screen for a login page. Here is the HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Jag City Job Management System</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
<script src="jag.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<br>
<table class='title'>
<tr><td align = 'left'><img src='jaguar.jpg'></td><td><h1 class='title'>Jag City
Management System</h1></td><td align='right'><img src='jaguar.jpg'></td></tr>
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
</table>
<?php
$d = date('d/m/Y');
?>
<table style='text-align:right;width:95%'>
<tr><td align = 'right'><?echo $d;?></td></tr>
</table>
<br>
<br>
<p class="thick">Please enter your User Name and Password to use the system.</p>
<form name="login" action= 'login.php' method='POST'>
<table border='0' style="text-align:left;width:270px">
<tr><td>User Name:</td><td><input type='text' name='eid'></td><tr>
<tr><td>Password:</td><td><input type='password' name='pword'></td><tr>
</table>
<br>
<input type='submit' value='Enter'>
<input type="button" onclick="lhelp()" value="Help">
</form>
<br>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is my .js file:

```
function lhelp() {
myWindow=window.open('/loginhelp.html','Help','width=750,height=250');
}

function jobadd()
{
var table = document.getElementById("jsadd");
var rowCount = table.rows.length;
var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
var i = rowCount + 1;
var x = rowCount - 1;

var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
var element1 = document.createElement("input");
element1.type = "text";
element1.name="job["+x+"]";
cell1.appendChild(element1);

var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
var element2 = document.createElement("input");
element2.type = "text";
element2.name="item["+x+"]";
cell2.appendChild(element2);

var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
var element3 = document.createElement("input");
element3.type = "text";
element3.name="cat["+x+"]";
cell3.appendChild(element3);

var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
var element4 = document.createElement("input");
element4.type = "text";
element4.name="desc["+x+"]";
cell4.appendChild(element4);

var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
var element5 = document.createElement("input");
element5.type = "text";
element5.name="hrest["+x+"]";
cell5.appendChild(element5);

var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
var element6 = document.createElement("input");
element6.type = "text";
element6.name="hract["+x+"]";
element6.value = "0";
cell6.appendChild(element6);

var cell7 = row.insertCell(6);
var element7 = document.createElement("input");
element7.type = "text";
element7.name="assign["+x+"]";
cell7.appendChild(element7);

var counter = document.getElementById("row");
counter.value = x;
}

function newf(z)
{
var compbut = document.getElementById("compno");
compbut.value = z.rowIndex;
var a = document.getElementById("act");
a.value = prompt("Enter Actual Hours for Job","0");
document.forms["notcomp"].submit();
}
```

It works perfectly in Firefox. I have other functions which also work the same way, works in FF but not the other two. I am hoping that any help I get to solve this will point me in the right direction for the rest.
One thing to note, Javascript must be working to a degree because a cursor change for a part of a table I have works in all three!

Comment: Any error message in the console?

Comment: Works for me in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/gVq7L/

Comment: ok, weird. Your link works for me too in Chrome but my original won't work!! Console says lhelp is not defined?!?

Comment: If it says it isn't defined, then most likely the JS isn't included, it is within another scope (unlikely in this case) or lhelp has being overwritten by other Javascript.

Comment: I'm a PHP man mainly and this is my first serious foray into Javascript, so I might have made a cock up somewhere, but the fact that it works perfectly in FF tells me I'm almost there with nothing serious wrong. i have posted all the code in the hope that it will help.

Comment: Probably the browsers are parsing your JS differently and being more/less sensitive to your mistakes. If the error is that `Ihelp` isn't defined, probably something references a call to it before the function was defined. You may need to physically move it in the HTML.

Comment: You were spot on, see my answer lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer!! In my original .js file, I had an old function left over from a previous project the I copied the .js file from and modified it for this project.  All of the lines from another function weren't terminated with a semi-colon.  I removed the old function and checked all the lines in the file were correctly terminated and it now works.
Many thanks to all who tried to help!!!